# SAS proc means equivalent in Redshift

Tags: sas, amazon-redshift

I want to convert a SAS code into redshift code.
We have proc means procedure in SaS,

```
proc means data=table0 noprint, nway missing;
id a ,b
class  x
var qty
output out=table1 sum = ;
```

Example:
Input
[image]

Required Output:
[image]

I wanted an equivalent code in redshift. The usual group by will not work here.

Comment: Hmmmm...that is an interesting result. I await to hear from SAS gurus here on the `qty` result. I get the other columns picking max values. Something to do with `_TYPE_` and `nway`. I hope OP is showing all input and all output data.

Comment: Please post data as text, not photographs.    Also show what Redshift SQL code you tried and explain how it did not meet your needs.

Comment: The values returned for the ID variables appear to be taken from the first value seen for that combination of the class (group by) variables.  Is it really of any importance to mimic that behavior?  If you want a specific values of A and/or B can you describe which value you want?

Comment: Well that isn't valid SAS code that would generate that output aside from the syntax errors. Do you have the actual SAS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n1niocuk07q2wnn16mz96fboupgc.htm):

> When you specify only one variable in the ID statement, the value of
> the ID variable for a given observation is the maximum (minimum) value
> found in the corresponding group of observations in the input data
> set. When you specify multiple variables in the ID statement, PROC
> MEANS selects the maximum value by processing the variables in the ID
> statement in the order in which you list them. PROC MEANS determines
> which observation to use from all the ID variables by comparing the
> values of the first ID variable. If more than one observation contains
> the same maximum (minimum) ID value, then PROC MEANS uses the second
> and subsequent ID variable values as “tiebreakers.” In any case, all
> ID values are taken from the same observation for any given BY group
> or classification level within a type.

So the ID values are chosen, maximum of the first variable (`a`), then if there are multiple `b` values for that maximum it chooses the maximum of those.

One way to do this would be to do the `group by` first, ignoring the `id` variables, and then separately determine the `id` variable values, finally joining those together.

Something like this...

```
data test;
  input x a b;
  var=0;
  datalines;
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 1
;;;;
run;

proc means data=test nway;
  id a b;
  class x;
  var var;
  output out=test_out sum=;
run;


proc sql;
  select m_a.x, m_a.a, m_b.b from (
  select x, max(a)  as a
  from test
  group by x ) m_a
  left join 
  ( select x, a, max(b) as b
    from test
    group by x, a
  ) m_b
  on m_a.x=m_b.x and m_a.a=m_b.a
  ;
quit;
```

Then you join that back to the normal 'group by' dataset just grouping by the class variable.